# Effective CSS layout switching for Right-to-Left languages

Tags: css, interface, sass, translation

At the moment, my usual approach to supporting right-to-left (RTL) languages in a template is to simply add a `.rtl` class to the `body` tag, then go through all my existing left-to-right CSS and add left/right overrides as appropriate.

For example, my site menu might be positioned like so by default as below:

```
.site-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

...and then manually overridden for RTL languages this way (using some template logic at a CMS level to add the `.rtl` class to `body`):

```
.rtl .site-nav {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

My issue is that this seems labour-intensive and not very effecient. I was wondering what solutions others might have come up with to make this simpler.

*As an aside, I'm using a Compass environment to generate my CSS. But I don't know how to escape back from the current nesting to write a `.rtl` modifier adjacent to the current element's default styles. This in theory would be extremely useful, however, but I simply don't know if it's possible to perform a lookup all the way back to the `body` element or not whilst within a deeply-nested Sass rule.*

Answer (score 0):

Add your .rtl-class whereever you want to change the textflow. Even when you don't want to change it (for "normal" languages).

Don't use the class in your default css-file.

Add a css-file which only includes

```
.rtl {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

whenever you have a rtl-language. In case you want all your divs to behave that you you could replace `.rtl` with `div` as well.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you please provide more information? Also, I'm concerned about having multiple CSS files and increasing the download overhead accordingly—this site is responsive, so needs to be well optimised and have as small an initial payload as is reasonable.

Comment: If you have to worry about one css-file you shouldn't do css at all. Just add the class .rtl to every element that should support the right to left-direction. Include the css-file with the right to left-settings only if you want to have your elements to be displayed that way. If the file is not included your elements will still have the .rtl-class, but since it is empty it will not effect the elements.